# [Identity Server]: What is the difference between AspNetUserClaims , ClientClaims and ScopeClaims

Tags: identityserver4, identity, identityserver3

1. What is the scope and claim in identity server and how we will use
   scope and claims?
2. We have scopes and claims in two places 
      -Client scopes and secrets
      -Scopes and Secrets
3. where we will use client scopes and claims?
4. **AspNetUserClaims**, where we will use this?

I was not getting these terms and confusing a lot while referring to the various documents and articles.

So, Can one help out on this?